# Nearest neighbour path using a two dimensional array for distance

Tags: python, list, distance, nested-lists, nearest-neighbor

I am trying to build a path using the nearest neighbours. I have a two-dimensional list for the distances between two nodes, and I have previously filled in the list like so:

```
distance[i][j]
```

I want the path to start with node 0, end at node 8 and I also want the path to having 8 nodes in total. So the returning path should be:

```
[0, a, b, c, d, e, f, 8]
```

In my code, I am starting with node zero, and successfully finding the nearest node from 0, which is 10. But for the rest of the nearest nodes, I am also getting 10. So after finding the first nearest node, I cannot find the next nearest node from 10. What my code is outputting is:

```
[0, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 8]
```

Why isn't my code updating the current node for the next nearest neighbours? What am I missing to find the next nearest neighbour from 10 and so on?
Thanks in advance!

```
        startNode = 0
        endNode = 8
        path = [0]*8 # Create a list for the path
        path[0] = startNode # Add the starting point
        path[endNode-1] = endNode # Add the end point

        currentNode = startNode
        
        for i in range(1, endNode-2): #index 1 to 6 because path[0]=0 and path[7]=8
            a = currentNode + 1
            closest = distance[currentNode][a]
            for j in range(a+1, endNode-1):
                if distance[currentNode][j] < closest :
                    closest = distance[currentNode][j] 
            currentNode = j
            path[i] = currentNode # Add the closest node to the new permutation list

        return path
```

Comment: This problem can be converted to a Graph, and Dijkstras algorithm can be used.

Answer (score 0):

The closest node to any node is itself, with a distance of zero

Answer (score 0):

Matrix of distances used, the only special thing being that the distance between 0 and 10 is 0 to make 10 the shortest node from 0, as in problem description.

```
np.random.seed(4)
distances=np.random.randint(1,30,(11,11))
x=np.triu(distances)
y=x+np.transpose(x)
for i in range(11):
    y[i,i]=999
y[0,10]=0
y[10,0]=0
print(y)

[[999  15  24   6   2   9  24   9  19  10   0]
 [ 15 999  14  24  24  26   9   5  19  13   7]
 [ 24  14 999   1  24  22  22  10   7   7  25]
 [  6  24   1 999  18   3  27  24   1   9  20]
 [  2  24  24  18 999  29   4  19  20  16   3]
 [  9  26  22   3  29 999  10  28  17  13  24]
 [ 24   9  22  27   4  10 999   7   8  14  11]
 [  9   5  10  24  19  28   7 999  16   5  28]
 [ 19  19   7   1  20  17   8  16 999  23   8]
 [ 10  13   7   9  16  13  14   5  23 999  22]
 [  0   7  25  20   3  24  11  28   8  22 999]]
```

Your code doesn't actually output [0, 10, 10, ..., 10, 8]. It looks like it outputs [0, 6, 6, 6, 6,..., 6, 8], because of currentNode=j after the for loop ends, just puts j=6 in currentNode every time. A modification of your code that works.

```
distance=y
for i in range(1, endNode-1): #index 1 to 6 because path[0]=0 and path[7]=8
    closest = 999
    nextNode=-1
    for j in range(1, 11):
        if np.isin(j, path):
            continue
        if distance[currentNode][j] < closest :
            closest = distance[currentNode][j] 
            nextNode = j
    path[i] = nextNode
    currentNode= nextNode

print(path)
[0, 10, 4, 6, 7, 1, 9, 8]
```

Comment: Where did the 999 come from?

Comment: When you start each loop set the closest distance to something very big so that the first node will be picked